# Cannot get the next value from a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, timer

I am trying to make an interval timer but cannot find a way of finding the next value in the list. It is a problem I have had for a while now and cant seem to get around it.

```
            def start_timer():
                global value
                value = (int(intarray[1]))+1 #finds the first value in the list
                dowvalue = (int(intarray[1]))+1 #also finds the first value to find the next later on
                def downcount():
                    global dowvalue
                    global valueup
                    global value
                    value = value-1 #counting down the value 
                    valuelab = Label(window, text=value).place(x=400, y=400)
                    print(value)
                    if value>0:
                        window.after(1000, downcount)#creats a one second gap between 
                    else:
                        value = intarray.index(dowvalue) + 1 #trying to find the next value in list
                        window.after(1000, downcount)
                if value or value>0:
                    downcount()
                else:
                    endlab = Label(window, text= END).place(x=400, y=400)
```

being clear I know that 'intarray' can be undefined and I shall work on this after I sort this.
'intarray' is a list that the user can input into

I have tried using a value that goes up after the value gets to 0 which didn't work due to the number being supposedly undefined. the closest I have gotten has been using index and adding 1 getting the next value but it just tells me that the original value is undefined.

Comment: Do you have context of how the intarray gets filled? does it look like [5, 10, 15] for instance?

Comment: Its all integers so yeah this would be valid

Answer (score 1):

I assumed some code and imports. The first problem is how you access the intarray. A pythonic way of accessing a value in an array is by calling the first index, `intarray[0]`. By using `iter` on your array you can access the next value using `iterator`.

Note that the code below only counts down the first value in your `intarray`.

```py
from tkinter import *

intarray = [5, 10, 15]
window = Tk()

def start_timer():
    global value
    value = intarray[0]  # set initial value to first value in list

    def downcount():
        global value
        value -= 1 # shorthand
        valuelab = Label(window, text=value)
        valuelab.place(x=400, y=400)
        print(value)
        if value > 0:
            window.after(1000, downcount)
        else:
            try:
                value = next(iterator)
                window.after(1000, downcount)
            except StopIteration:
                endlab = Label(window, text="END")
                endlab.place(x=400, y=400)

    downcount()
    print(value)

iterator = iter(intarray)
start_timer()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This does create the desired results but the problem is that after the first countdown the first index a second time. Can 'next' be used at the 1st index or does 'iter' always start at the 0th index?

Comment: Well you could use `intarray.pop(0)` as suggested by Michael Cao. Call this in your end except clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.pop(0)` to remove the first value from your list and store it under `value`. This way, the next value is always in the 0th index of your list. To prevent accessing an empty list, you can just use `if intarray`.

```
if intarray:
    value = intarray.pop(0)
```